# How does logical channels separation is implemented over one physical in RabbitMQ ?

Tags: tcp, rabbitmq, messaging

I am current reading in depth about RabbitMQ as I will have a task working with it. I've read about channels. In [RabbitMQ Essentials](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/rabbitmq-essentials)

"Channel: This is a logical connection between a publisher/consumer and
a broker. Multiple channels can be established within a single connection."

Can some explain a bin in details how this is accomplished. I can imagine that a channel represents some kind of a publisher/consumer where they send use the TCP channel IN TURNs, for example in Round Robin fashion. when a logical channel is using the physical one other channels wait until the current is finished then its passed to the next logical channel. Is this  assumption is true or I am missing something ?

Comment: This one question looks quite similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060548/how-does-rabbitmq-supports-large-number-of-virtual-connections-from-a-single-tcp

Comment: Yes I guess it is. I will check right now, Thank you